# How to get array element using XSLT

Tags: arrays, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to create a XSLT function that takes in an array and an integer (representing a position) and returns the element at the given position. This is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:function name="getArrayPosition" as="item()*">
  <xsl:param name="position"/>
  <xsl:param name="srcCodesArray" as="item()*"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$srcCodesArray[$position]"/>
</xsl:function>
```

My input will be something very simple, such as

```
<srcCodes>
  <item>Test1</item>
  <item>Test2</item>
</srcCodes>
```

Comment: I think you have your answer, but next time it would be good to let people know what result you're getting from the code you have, and how it differs from the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass in an `xs:integer` then your code should work to select an item by its position. But I would suggest to simply declare the variable of that type e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="position" as="xs:integer"/>
```

(where you put the namespace declaration `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` on the `xsl:stylesheet`), then it should work even if string values are passed in that can be cast to an integer or a node whose string value can be cast to an integer.

And of course doing `<xsl:value-of select="$srcCodesArray[$position]"/>` does not return the item itself but rather creates a text node with the string value of the item. So you want

```
<xsl:sequence select="$srcCodesArray[$position]"/>
```

instead.

Finally I would suggest to learn and use the proper terminology, the XSLT/XPath/XQuery data model does not have any *arrays*, it has *sequences*.